# MySQL assign var in SELECT but not display it

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
SET @id := '';
SELECT 
  libs.song_id,
  songs.name AS song_name,
  artists.id AS artist_id,
  artists.name AS artist_name,
  songs.description,
  libs.status,
  libs.activated,
  libs.giftable,
  @id := libs.song_id,
  IF((SELECT activated FROM libs WHERE @id = song_id && activated = 1), 1, 0) AS duplicate
FROM libs, songs, artists
WHERE
  libs.song_id = songs.id &&
  artists.id = songs.artist_id &&
  libs.activated = 0 &&
  libs.user_id = '1';
```

Everything goes as planned but I get also a column named `@id := libs.song_id`, how can I avoid it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A few things first.  Learn to use proper join syntax.  A simple rule:  Just don't use commas in the `from` clause.

Second, you don't even have to initialize the variable as a separate statement.

Third, the idea is simple.  Just assign the variable in another expression and there is a very natural place to do it:

```
SELECT (@id := libs.song_id) as song_id,
       songs.name AS song_name, artists.id AS artist_id, artists.name AS artist_name,
       songs.description, libs.status, libs.activated, libs.giftable,
       IF((SELECT activated FROM libs WHERE @id = song_id AND activated = 1), 1, 0) AS duplicate
FROM libs join
     songs
     on libs.song_id = songs.id join
     artists
     on artists.id = songs.artist_id
WHERE libs.activated = 0 AND libs.user_id = '1';
```

Comment: Yeah, I found out by myself that the SET statement was useless. Thanks!